# how to make the button from second alert dialog navigate to previous alert dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

so I have this alert dialog that has two option button. If I click "yes" but with wrong input, it'll create another dialog that reminds you to input the right text.

```
ab.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    kode_konfirmasi = userInput.getText().toString();
                    if(kode_konfirmasi.equals("lrsstwbsd")) {
                        strIdWaktuVaksin = ambil_notif_id_vaksin;
                        strWaktuDatang = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
                        strStatusVaksin = "done";

                        update(strIdWaktuVaksin, strWaktuDatang, strStatusVaksin);

                        new LongOperation().execute(url);
                    }else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder abt = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPetInformation.this);
                        abt.setTitle("sorry, wrong input. Try again");
                        abt.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                        abt.show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

but, i don't know how to make the second dialog button navigate to previous dialog where the user can input again

Comment: You can simply dismiss the second dialog on button click so that previous dialog is still visible

Comment: rather than create new one, you should update existing one

Comment: do not create `ok` button on second dialog, just show the error massage and dismiss the dialog...

Comment: @kevz care to give me sample code?

Comment: @kishorejethava i've tried it, how to make sure it doesn't dismiss automatically after input?

else{
                        tvResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tvResult.setText("wrong input");
                        return;
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create AlertDialog as below -

```
final AlertDialog ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("First")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) //Set to null. We override the onclick
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .create();

    ab.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button b = ab.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder1.setTitle("second");
                    builder1.setPositiveButton("okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            abt.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                    abt = builder1.create();
                    abt.show();

                    if(correctInput)
                        // ab.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    ab.show();
```

Create AlertDialog abt as Class Member.

Comment: @Lia Dianti: check the edited answer works as your expection :D

Comment: where do i put abt as class member?

Comment: @Lia Dianti: Inside your MainActivity, outside onCreate() method.

Comment: you mean like this? final AlertDialog abt = null;

Comment: @Lia Dianti:You don't have to use keyword final if its a class member.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100016/discussion-between-kevz-and-lia-dianti).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would recommend to use [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) with [LENGTH_LONG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) to show your error as it dispose it self after some time and your `AlertDialog` will be still there...

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But if you want to use `Alertdialog`  make your `AlertDialog` object global variable and call it in you second dialog `onClick`.

```
AlertDialog _alert;

final AlertDialog.Builder _builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    _builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             if(condition) {
               // ---- 
             }else{
                AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Wrong Input");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     _alert = _builder.create();
                     _alert.show();
                   //-- return to first dialog
                 }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            });
    _alert = _builder.create();
    _alert.show()
```